# Worklight Server not starting

Tags: worklight-server

hello i am using ibm worklight application development platform v 6.0.1. I am having a problem with the worklight server, which was working nicely till now. Whenever i try to start the server, it does not and displays the following error:
*Worklight server was unable to start within 120 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.*
i increased the timeout many times but the problem still persisted. Can anyone help?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the following documentation Worklight has provided with the issue described above:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21668175

A solution is provided below:

```
To resolve this problem, you can apply one or both of the following workarounds.

    Complete the following steps to increase the timeout default value:
        1.Open the Servers view.

        2.Double-click the Worklight Development Server to open the Overview pane.

        3.Expand the Timeouts section.

        4.Increase the value in the Start (in seconds) field. Consider doubling the default value; that is, set it to 120 seconds.

    Complete the following steps to remove the unnecessary applications from Worklight Development Server.
        1.Open the Servers view.

        2.Right-click the Worklight Development Server.

        3.Select the Add and Remove option.

        4.Remove all applications that you do not intend to work on.



After you have made any of these changes to the configuration, restart the server.
```

As you can see having a lot of applications deployed to your sever may cause the startup time to increase. Have you tried increasing the time beyond 120s as your error indicates?