# I can't run my mobile app on worklight development server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

> FWLPL0010W: "localhost" was detected from the target server
>   configuration. Using the primary IP address of the host machine,
>   197.255.122.78,  to build the Worklight application(s). Consider using a fully qualified hostname (avoid using "localhost") or a valid IP
>   address instead.  The value can be modified by opening the
>   configuration editor of Worklight Development Server from the
>   "Servers" view.
>
> [2015-01-10 12:34:11]
>   com.worklight.studio.plugin.nls.Messages:FWLPL0001W: Server not
>   started yet. Build may fail at first trial.  [2015-01-10 12:34:11]
>   FWLPL0017E: Worklight Console can not be opened because the Worklight
>   Server is not running. Right-click the server 'Worklight Development 
>   Server' from "Servers" view and select "Start" from the menu to start
>   the server.

Comment: Abdul, You must put more effort into your question. Pasting 2 log entries will get this question closed real fast. Explain your scenario and whether or not you have followed the instructions in the error. Also note that the first log is not an error - read it.

Comment: ok thank you well i cant get past running on worklight development server... and i aslo cant open worklight console

Comment: Did you try the suggestion per the error? Did you go to the Servers view in Eclipse and click the green 'play' button in order to start the server? If yes, do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: it tells me "Server Worklight Development Server was unable to start within 120 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor." and "Server Worklight Development Server failed to stop." also the console says [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application _MobileBrowserSimulator cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application AKIp cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.

Comment: What is your worklight version and build number (from Eclipse > Help), as well as your OS.

Comment: am using eclipse Juno Service Release 2 build no. 20130225-0426 my os is windows 8

Comment: Worklight version and build number, not Eclipse version.

Comment: sorry the version is 6.1.0.02 and build no. is 20141216-0421

Comment: @Abdul I had a similar problem, your advices helped me finding a solution. Thanks a lot Abdul!

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment, the issue appears to be the following:

> Server Worklight Development Server was unable to start within 120
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

A Google search brought up the following same question: [Worklight Server not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221610/worklight-server-not-starting)

The solution was provided per the instructions in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21668175:

```
To resolve this problem, you can apply one or both of the following workarounds.

    Complete the following steps to increase the timeout default value:
        1.Open the Servers view.

        2.Double-click the Worklight Development Server to open the Overview pane.

        3.Expand the Timeouts section.

        4.Increase the value in the Start (in seconds) field. Consider doubling the default value; that is, set it to 120 seconds.

    Complete the following steps to remove the unnecessary applications from Worklight Development Server.
        1.Open the Servers view.

        2.Right-click the Worklight Development Server.

        3.Select the Add and Remove option.

        4.Remove all applications that you do not intend to work on.
```

After you have made any of these changes to the configuration, restart the server.